# How to plot three Simultaneous graphs on the same axis?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I'm new in this domain of Chaos & MATLAB coding. I've a problem as described below.

Expected output: I'm trying to get the exact phase plane plots & time series plot of Aceng Sambas et.al. system as shown in the figure down below of his paper.
The first figure shows phase plain portrait & the second figure shows the time domain response. The link for this paper is provided here [[1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8789476)]. {This material was taken from the net}

Problem statement: I'm not able to obtain multiple plots of graphs on the same axis & I'm not able to understand the logic behind obtaining multiple plots on the same axes.

How I proceeded: I started to write down the code for this system as there are three different values of parameters K, I tried to solve them separately and later on I tried to obtain the plot for all the three different values of K.

Result that I obtained: I'm not able to get the desired Phase plain plot in 2-d & time series plot (or time domain - It is a plot for state v/s time). I founded certain MATLAB comment that was useful in plotting multiple plots together & I did incorporated them but no luck.

.

I've provided my codes down below, Please excuse me In case if I've provided with too much of codes.

```
function  Aceng_Sambas_Parameter_Boosting
function  Aceng_Sambas_Parameter_Boosting_2
function  Aceng_Sambas_Parameter_Boosting_3
t0 = 0; % Initial point
tn = 600; % Terminal point
Y0 = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]; % Initial values

a = 5;b = 2;k1=0;% system parameters
a = 5;b = 2;k2=2;% system parameters
a = 5;b = 2;k3=5;% system parameters

[t, Y] = ode45(@ Aceng_Sambas_Parameter_Boosting, [t0, tn], Y0); %Solving the equations 
[t2, Y2] = ode45(@ Aceng_Sambas_Parameter_Boosting_2, [t0, tn], Y0);%Solving the equations 
[t3, Y3] = ode45(@ Aceng_Sambas_Parameter_Boosting_3, [t0, tn], Y0);%Solving the equations 

% Create a(2-D)Plot 
plot(Y(:,2),Y(:,3),Y2(:,2),Y2(:,3),Y3(:,2),Y3(:,3),'Color', [0.72,0.27,1.00],'-r','-g') 
xlabel('y')
ylabel('z')
legend
title(' Aceng_Sambas System')
hold on
fig()

% Time series plot

plot(t,Y(:,3),t2,Y2(:,3),t3,Y3(:,3),'Color', [0.72,0.27,1.00],'-r','-g')
xlabel('t')
ylabel('z')
legend
title('Aceng_Sambas System')
hold on
fig()

  function dYdt =  Aceng_Sambas_Parameter_Boosting(~,X) %System equation for different values of k

    dxdt =  X(2)*(X(3)+k1);
    dydt = X(1)-X(2);
    dzdt = a*abs(X(1))- b*X(1)^2;
    dYdt = [dxdt; dydt; dzdt];

    function dYdt =  Aceng_Sambas_Parameter_Boosting_2(~,H) %System equation for different values of k

    dxdt =  H(2)*(H(3)+k2);
    dydt = H(1)-H(2);
    dzdt = a*abs(H(1))- b*H(1)^2;
    dYdt = [dxdt; dydt; dzdt];

    function dYdt =  Aceng_Sambas_Parameter_Boosting_3(~,P) %System equation for different values of k

    dxdt =  P(2)*(P(3)+k3);
    dydt = P(1)-P(2);
    dzdt = a*abs(P(1))- b*P(1)^2;
    dYdt = [dxdt; dydt; dzdt];

    end
    end

end
end
    end
    end
```

[image: Phase plain Portrait as shown in their research paper- the desired result that I need][image: Time domain plot as shown in their research paper- the desired result that I need]

Comment: What is the output and what is the expected output? I’m unclear as to what the actual problem is. Do you mean that you’d like all three plots to be in the same axes? Or in different axes but in the same figure? Right now it looks like you create separate figures for each plot. The `figure` command creates a new figure window, try removing those statements.

Comment: @Cris Luengo: I've written the problem again. I did incorporated those changes that you have mentioned before but I'm still not able to get the plot.

Comment: @Cris Luengo: For different values of 'K' I need all of their behavior on one axis, i.e between z & y as shown in the paper for phase portrait & between 'z'-axis & t for time domain behavior, just as shown in their paper.